# Upload de imagem React Axios e PHP

Tags: php, react, upload, axios

Preciso fazer um sistema de postagem que inclui imagem e dados da postagem com *ReactJS*, *Axios* e *PHP*(sim, php).

**No ReactJS**

```
const post = async (formData) => {
    const image = new FormData()
    image.append('imageFile', formData.imageFile[0])

    const config = {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    }

    await api.post('informations/createInformation', image, config)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
        })
} // post
```

No PHP eu consigo recuperar o arquivo acessando a váriável *superglobal* `$_FILES`:

```
public function createInformation(): void
{
    print_r($_FILES);
} // createInformation
```

O código acima imprime:

```
Array 
(
    [imageFile] => Array 
    (
        [name] => teste.png
        [type] => image/svg+xml
        [tmp_name] => /opt/lampp/temp/php6BLbIr
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 22315
    )
)
```

Usando o axios para fazer requisições para a api PHP, não é possível acessá-los pela variável superglobal `$_POST`, só é possível recuperar os dados da seguinte maneira:

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
```

Porém, para enviar a imagem na requisição, não é possível colocá-la dentro de um objeto JavaScript, apenas colocando a imagem sozinha como dado do post:

**Funciona**

```
await api.post('informations/createInformation', imagem, config)
```

**Não funciona**

```
await api.post('informations/createInformation', { outrosDados, imagem }, config)
```

Da segunda maneira, o servidor recebe o `array` `$_FILES` vazio, e da primeira maneira não consigo enviar os dados da postagem junto com a imagem.

O que preciso é de um post com a imagem E os dados da postagem(usuário, título, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar as informações de texto (título, usuário) no objeto FormData.

```
const frm = new FormData()
frm.append('imageFile', formData.imageFile[0])
frm.append('titulo', 'Título')
```

*Use o `print_r` na superglobal `$_REQUEST` para validar a requisição recebida.

Comment: Sua resposta está correta e provavelmente vai resolver o problema da pergunta, mas eu acho que vale explicar o porquê de `{ outrosDados, imagem }` não estar funcionando. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes:

Primeiro criamos uma função para passar para base64 a imagem e mandala na API:

```
//Author James Harrington 2014 modified by Doctorspeppers
function base64(file){
  var coolFile = {};
  function readerOnload(e){
    var base64 = btoa(e.target.result);
    coolFile.base64 = base64;
    return coolFile
  };

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = readerOnload;

  var file = file[0].files[0];
  coolFile.filetype = file.type;
  coolFile.size = file.size;
  coolFile.filename = file.name;
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

Após isso implementamos no código:

`await api.post('informations/createInformation', { outrosDados, base64(imagem) }, config)`

Do lado do servidor fazemos a seguinte alteração

```
<?php 
$imagem = base64_decode($_POST['imagem']);
?>
```